# Making a little rpg, but can't get the value of a variable in one function to another function without calling the entire function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am basically trying to get a variable (strength0, strength1, strength2, depending on what user chooses) from function 'gym' to the function 'local_badass'. If I try to catch it with return it calls the entire function thus going back a step in the game.

Just wondering if there is a way to get the variable, with it's value, depending on what the user chooses so I can use the variables (strength0, strength1 and strength2) in the future levels of the game and so they have an impact on what the user can do in the game e.g. if strength < 2 cannot defeat the dragon.

```
def start():
    print("Hi there, you are sitting in your room.")
    print("A voice inside your head says let's go and have some fun.")
    print("You have two options.")
    print("1. Go to the gym.")
    print("2. Go elsewhere.")
    choice = input(">   ")

    if choice == "1":
        gym(list(range(3)))
    elif choice == "2":
        elsewhere()

def bedroom():
    print("You are back in your bedroom after the gym.")
    print("You have one option: ")
    print("1. Go elsewhere.")
    choice = input(">   ")

    if choice == "1":
        start()

def gym(strength):
    print("You arrive at the gym, your muscles are aching for some action.")
    print("Do you wish to go hard or take it easy, or not bother at all?")
    print("0. Enough of this, let's go home.")
    print("1. Go soft, I don't want to risk injury.")
    print("2. Go hard, I was born for this.")
    choice_gym = input(">   ")

    if choice_gym == "0":
        print("You are tired just walking to the gym and decide to go home.")
        global strength0
        strength0 = strength.pop(0)
        print(f"Strength is: {strength0}")
        bedroom()


    elif choice_gym == "1":
        print("You take it easy, but make some gains.")
        global strength1
        strength1 = strength.pop(1)
        print("Strength is now: ", strength1)
        bedroom()


    elif choice_gym == "2":
        print("You go hard, dripping sweat and testosterone everywhere.")
        print("Boy do you feel strong.")
        strength2 = strength.pop(2)
        print("Strength is now: ", strength2)
        bedroom()


    else:
        print("Invalid selection, please try again.")
        gym(list(range(3)))

def dead():
    print("Your are dead. Bad luck.")
    exit(0)

def elsewhere():

    print("You leave your house, a slight breeze ruffles your hair as you look around.\nYou pull a map out of your pocket and see 3 things you can do.")
    print("1. Challenge the local badass.")
    print("2. Challenge the UFC champion.")
    print("3. Defeat the dragon.")
    choice = input(">   ")

    if choice == "1":
        print("You have chosen the local badass.")
        print("Seeking out local badass...")
        local_badass()

def local_badass():
    if strength1 > 0 or strength2 > 0:
        print("You whooped his ass.")
    else:
        print("You got your ass kicked.")



start()
```

Comment: Have you considered declaring a class with those variables to be used in your functions?

Comment: You could use global variables, but a class solution is better (as suggested by @DaveStSomeWhere).

Comment: what is the global `strength0`?  What is the purpose of calling `pop()` on it?  (this looks wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to have a global list of player stats.  This seems like what you're doing already with `strength`.

Maybe make a class to keep them all in:

```
class Player:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.strength1  = 10
        self.strength2  = 10
        self.luck       = 7.3
        self.muchness   = 12
```

You need to create an *instance* of the `Player`:

```
player_stats = Player()
```

But then you can access this inside your functions:

```
def local_badass():
    global player_stats
    if player_stats.strength1 > 0 or player_stats.strength2 > 0:
        print("You whooped his ass.")
    else:
        print("You got your ass kicked.")
```

Global variables are generally frowned upon though.  So if you like, you could pass the player stats to every single function, but that seems a bit pointless in this case.

If I may offer some advice... it may be worthwhile to create a single `getUserInput()` function that can accept range-options, and handle all the bad-input, errors, quitting etc.  This would be better than calling `input()` every time, and checking separately repeatedly.

Something like:

```
def getUserInput( prompt, min_input, max_input ):
    """ Get a valid number from the user that's between min & max.
        If the user inputs "quit", exit the program.
        Keep prompting until a valid option is entered.              """
    result = None
    while ( result == None ):                    # Asking until we get valid input
        choice = input( prompt )
        choice = choice.trim().lower()
        if ( choice == 'quit' or choice == 'exit' ):
            print( "\nbye..." )
            sys.exit( 0 )
        else:
            try:
                number = int( choice )           # Did the user enter a valid number?
            except:
                pass  
            # Did we get valid input?
            if ( number >= min_input and number <= max_input ):                   
                # Correct input, set the result 
                result = str( number )           # Convert result back to string
            else:
                # The input was invalid, loop around again
                print( "Valid input is a number %d → %d, or \"quit\"\n" % ( min_input, max_input ) )
    return result
```